# Is there any way to decompile grails/groovy jar file?

Tags: grails, gradle, groovy, jar, decompiling

I have a **groovy/grails jar** file. I want to decompile it into groovy files. Is there any tool to do that. I have tried some online decopilers , they all decmpile the files into **java** not **groovy**. I have created the jar using **gradle jar** command. I'm using **grails version 3.1.11 and groovy version: 2.4.7** and **gradle verion: 2.13**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use any Java decompiler, but you will not get Groovy code back, as no such tool exists (to my knowledge)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the weaknesses of non-Java JVM languages.  Groovy does a lot of reflection and other such trickery in creating its bytecode, so if you decompile the .class file, you'll have a lot of noise.  This is similarly reflected in Groovy stacktraces.  You have to train yourself to find the signal despite all of the noise.  The good news is that both Eclipse and IntelliJ can debug Groovy code nicely, so you can step through to find the issue you're dealing with.

Comment: This is not so much the case with static compilation, which should be used everywhere possible